# Windsor not resolving intercepted components

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, interceptor

Can anyone explain why this doesn't work?  If you remove the interceptor from IFoo's registration and resolve a Bar, you get a Foo (MyFoo isn't null).  But with the interceptor, the Foo doesn't resolve anymore.

Why?  How can I tell why it won't resolve via logging or tracing?

Versions:

- Castle.Core: 3.2
- Castle.Windsor: 3.2
- .NET 4.5
- C# 5

  ```
  using Castle.DynamicProxy;
  using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
  using Castle.Windsor;
  using System;

  namespace Sandbox
  {
  public interface IFooInterceptor : IInterceptor { }

  public interface IFoo
  {
      void Print();
  }

  public interface IBar
  {
      IFoo MyFoo { get; set; }
  }

  public class Foo : IFoo
  {
      public void Print()
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Print");
      }
  }

  public class FooInterceptor : IFooInterceptor, IInterceptor
  {

      public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
      {
          Console.WriteLine("Awesome");
          invocation.Proceed();
      }
  }

  public class Bar : IBar
  {
      public virtual IFoo MyFoo { get; set; }
  }

  class Program
  {

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
          IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer()
              .Register(
                  Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().LifestyleTransient(),
                  Component.For<IFoo>().ImplementedBy<Foo>().LifestyleTransient().Interceptors<IFooInterceptor>(),
                  Component.For<IFooInterceptor>().ImplementedBy<FooInterceptor>().LifestyleTransient()
              );

          var bar = container.Resolve<IBar>();
          var foo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();  // this isn't null
          bar.MyFoo.Print();                    // exception: bar.MyFoo is null
          Console.WriteLine("Done");
          Console.ReadLine();
      }

  }
  }
  ```

**Edit:**  I just found (mostly by accident) that changing the interceptor config from an interface to a concrete class works.  However, I'm registering the interceptor and its interface, so the original question is amended slightly: why does the interface specification fail (silently, no less)?

Comment: I disagree with the removal of the Dynamicproxy tag.

Comment: It seems that this a bug. Proprieties are optional dependencies but they should be filled in by default but it conflicts with the interception somehow. If you make your dependency mandatory with `Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().LifestyleTransient().Properties(PropertyFilter.RequireAll)` it also works. I've found this issue on github: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/24 which feels related to this.

Comment: @nemesv I think you can post that as the answer so that the question does not remain unanswered. Providing Bar.MyFoo as constructor argument will also solve the problem.

Comment: it does not make sense to register interceptor as an inteface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Castle handles properties as optional dependencies but it should inject them by default. But it seems that combined with the Interceptors these optional dependencies are not resolved correctly.

What you can do you is to make your dependencies required by changing Bar to use constructor injection:

```
public class Bar : IBar
{
    public Bar(IFoo foo)
    {
        MyFoo = foo;
    }

    public virtual IFoo MyFoo { get; private set; }
}
```

Or register Bar with the `Properties` explicitly marked required:

```
Component.For<IBar>().ImplementedBy<Bar>().LifestyleTransient()
    .Properties(Prop‌​ertyFilter.RequireAll)
```

Note: in production you should use the `PropertiesRequired` method instead of the `Properties` because it is obsolete now.

I've also found this github issue which also seemed relevant: [Bug - optional dependencies not provided](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/issues/24)